# Apache2.4 can't start

Tags: apache-http-server, php

Need help in starting Apache in XAMPP, I had finished reconfiguring apache's and XAMPP's control panel to listen to port 8079. But there is still problem in starting it. The logs are below.

XAMPP Control Panel Log:

```
9:02:53 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
9:02:53 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:02:53 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:02:53 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:02:53 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:02:53 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
9:02:53 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Windows Event Viewer:

The Apache service named reported the following error:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 537 of
> C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of
> C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load
> /xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: The specified procedure could not
> be found

Syntax error on line 537 of httpd. conf:

> Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

Syntax error on line 17 of httpd-xampp. conf:

> LoadFile "/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"

Comment: Look at the full error: Note now all paths are prefixed by `C:`?  The path you set is `/xampp/php/php7ts.dll` which is more of a Linux/Unix path. Try setting it to `C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll` and see what happens.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 tried but the problem still persists

Comment: What is the full path to `php7ts.dll`?

Comment: @janhaxe23 Might help of you can post the full contents of `conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` into this question as code. Seems like a simple issue. Maybe even a case of Windows line encoding being munged with Unix/Linux line encoding? What editor did you use to adjust things?

Comment: @Anaksunaman its C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I used sublime text to edit conf files

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried to make any changes to your PHP version or are you using the version XAMPP installed?

Comment: @janhaxe23 Knowing you used SublimeText is fine; it means it would retain line endings. But can you please post the full contents of `conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` into this question as code?